# How to use step rather than continue to invoke watchpoint in GDB

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I have been using the following steps to keep a watch on variables in GDB and it works fine with me:

```
 1. set some breakpoints
 2. run
 3. watch a variable
 4. continue
```

However, in this [gdb youtube tutorial (start from 12:10)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQ0ONbt-qPs&t=728s), the author use step instead of continue to invoke watchpoint messages, the situation of which I was unable to reproduce.

The sample code was copied from the tutorial:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sum, i;
  char string[120];

  sum=0;
  strcpy(string, "Hello!");

  for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    sum+=i;
    sum=square(sum, i);
  }
  printf("sum=%d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}

int square(int big, int temp)
{
  int i;
  i=big;
  if(big>10) i=i%10;
  return(i*temp);
}
```

Here's the steps I tried to invoke watchpoint by "step" but failed (That is, even if I have set watchpoint, but the "Old value = " and "New value =" message wasn't shown):

```
 1. start
 2. step to main
 3. watch i
 4. step several times but none of watchpoint message was shown
```

What do I need to do to get it work with "step"? Thank you.

Here is my work environment:

> gdb version: 7.11.1 
>   OS: Ubuntu 16.04 on VMware player 12 in Win10

**Edited:** 
**1. This is the code which I used "continue" and worked fine with.**

```
syuan@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ gdb test

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005ae: file test.c, line 8.

(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/syuan/Downloads/test 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde48) at test.c:8
8   {
(gdb) watch i
Hardware watchpoint 2: i
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: i

Old value = 0
New value = 1
0x0000000000400615 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde48) at test.c:15
15    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: i

Old value = 1
New value = 2
0x0000000000400615 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde48) at test.c:15
15    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: i

Old value = 2
New value = 3
0x0000000000400615 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde48) at test.c:15
```

**2. This is the code which I used "step" or "next" but had no success.**

```
syuan@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ gdb test

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005ae: file test.c, line 8.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x4005ae: file test.c, line 8.
Starting program: /home/syuan/Downloads/test 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde48) at test.c:8
8   {
(gdb) step
12    sum=0;
(gdb) watch i
Hardware watchpoint 3: i
(gdb) step
13    strcpy(string, "Hello!");
(gdb) step
15    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
(gdb) step
16      sum+=i;
(gdb) step
17      sum=square(sum, i);
(gdb) step
square (big=0, temp=0) at test.c:26
26    i=big;
(gdb) step
27    if(big>10) i=i%10;
(gdb) step
28    return(i*temp);
(gdb) step
29  }
(gdb) step
main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde48) at test.c:15
15    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
(gdb) step
16      sum+=i;
(gdb) step
17      sum=square(sum, i);
(gdb) step
square (big=1, temp=1) at test.c:26
26    i=big;
(gdb) step
27    if(big>10) i=i%10;
(gdb) step
28    return(i*temp);
(gdb) step
29  }
(gdb) step
main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde48) at test.c:15
15    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
(gdb) step
16      sum+=i;
(gdb) step
17      sum=square(sum, i);
(gdb) step
square (big=3, temp=2) at test.c:26
26    i=big;
(gdb) step
27    if(big>10) i=i%10;
(gdb) step
28    return(i*temp);
(gdb) step
29  }
(gdb) step
main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde48) at test.c:15
15    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
(gdb) next
16      sum+=i;
(gdb) next
17      sum=square(sum, i);
(gdb) next
15    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
(gdb) next
16      sum+=i;
(gdb) next
17      sum=square(sum, i);
(gdb) next
15    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
(gdb) next
16      sum+=i;
(gdb) info watchpoint
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
3       hw watchpoint  keep y                      i
```

**Edited again**

**I've tested it on an online gdb tool with gdb 7.7.1, a linux server with gdb 7.11.1, and a PC running linux as HOST OS. All of them do work, which lead to an assumption that it might be a problem on VM, but this need more verification.**

Comment: Need to step to the line of code when the value of `i` changes.

Comment: Works for me. Have you stepped through the loop at least twice?

Comment: first please post some complete code [mcve]. Next: I tried breaking to `main`, running, watching i, stepping, and it works: cannot reproduce. Please post the actual commands you used and the gdb output. It's really unclear and vague whether you did an obvious mistake or not.

Comment: if you're just trying to go around the loop a few times, you'd be better off using "next" rather than "step" as "step" will enter any subroutines you encounter.

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness. I have edited the post and put two codes of different versions I ran. I had no problem with "continue", however, had no success on "step" or "next". I've run for several loops and type "info watchpoint" at the last command to confirm there is a watchpoint.

Comment: not reproducible here https://pastebin.com/7fXXpsDr How do you compile the program?

Comment: I used "gcc -g -o test test.c".

Comment: I've created a new VM (Mint 18.1) to test and it still doesn't work. However, if I use [online gdb](http://www.onlinegdb.com/) and it does work for me. That's really weird...

Comment: Maybe this doesn't work in a VM.

Comment: I've also tested it on a linux server of my lab (with gdb 7.11.1) and a PC which runs linux as a HOST OS, both of them work, so now I also consider it might be the problem of VM. Need more infos to verify the assumption.